# How to fix "cannot set a row with mismatched columns" error in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I'm creating a web scraper for a project of mine. I'm web scraping jobs from indeed. I'm able to get all the data that I need. Now I'm having a problem creating a dataframe to save it to a CSV file.

I have searched for the error and tried many possible solutions but I keep getting the same error. Appreciate any suggestions on code or error problem. Thank you

`ValueError: cannot set a row with mismatched columns`

```
import requests
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import pandas as pd
import time


max_results_per_city = 30

city_set = ['New+York','Chicago']
columns = ["city", "job_title", "company_name", "location", "summary"]

database = pd.DataFrame(columns = columns)

for city in city_set:
    for start in range(0, max_results_per_city, 10):
        page = requests.get('https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=computer+science&l=' + str(city) + '&start=' + str(start))
        time.sleep(1)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "lxml")
        for div in soup.find_all(name="div", attrs={"class":"row"}):
            num = (len(sample_df) + 1)
            job_post = []
            job_post.append(city)
            for a in div.find_all(name="a", attrs={"data-tn-element":"jobTitle"}):
                job_post.append(a["title"])
            company = div.find_all(name="span", attrs={"class":"company"})
            if len(company) > 0:
                for b in company:
                    job_post.append(b.text.strip())
            else:
                sec_try = div.find_all(name="span", attrs={"class":"result-link-source"})
                for span in sec_try:
                    job_post.append(span.text)
            
            c = div.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'location'})
            for span in c:
                 job_post.append(span.text)
            d = div.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'summary'})
            for span in d:
                job_post.append(span.text.strip())
            database.loc[num] = job_post
            database.to_csv("test.csv")
```

Comment: Thanks for your question, it looks like you've done really well, there's a few things that are giving you trouble. The main one is `job_post` being a list which can be a different length for each result, whereas Pandas DataFrames and CSVs should have the same number of columns. It would be more appropriate to use a `dict` or `tuple`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reproducing your code, it was not extracting `location` and `database` indentation is in the wrong place. So, fix `c = div.findAll(name='span', attrs={'class': 'location'})`
. Here's a fix that makes it work:

```
database = []

for city in city_set:
    for start in range(0, max_results_per_city, 10):
        page = requests.get('https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=computer+science&l=' + str(city) + '&start=' + str(start))
        time.sleep(1)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "lxml")
        for div in soup.find_all(name="div", attrs={"class":"row"}):
            #num = (len(sample_df) + 1)
            job_post = []
            job_post.append(city)
            for a in div.find_all(name="a", attrs={"data-tn-element":"jobTitle"}):
                job_post.append(a["title"])
            company = div.find_all(name="span", attrs={"class":"company"})
            if len(company) > 0:
                for b in company:
                    job_post.append(b.text.strip())
            else:
                sec_try = div.find_all(name="span", attrs={"class":"result-link-source"})
                for span in sec_try:
                    job_post.append(span.text)

            c = div.findAll(name='span', attrs={'class': 'location'})
            for span in c:
                 job_post.append(span.text)
            d = div.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'summary'})
            for span in d:
                job_post.append(span.text.strip())
        database.append(job_post)

df00=pd.DataFrame(database)
df00.shape


df00.columns=columns
df00.to_csv("test.csv",index=False)
```

[image: Web scrap]

Comment: I'm having an issue where some job summaries are in the location column instead of the summary column. I double check if these jobs had a location and they do.

Answer (score 0):

**This issue is caused by the # Columns not matching the amount of data (for at least one row).**

I see a number of issues: Where is 'sample_df' initialized, where are you adding data to 'database' are the big ones that pop out.

I'd restructure your code job_post looks like your row level list. I would use to append to a table level list, so at the end of each loop hit `table.append(job_post)` instead of `sample_df.loc[num] = job_post`

then after your loop you can call `Dataframe(table, columns=columns)`

**a note: make sure you're adding None, Null or "" when your scraper can't find data, otherwise your row length wont match your column length, which is what is causing your error.**